# Laravel Request undefined method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I´m using Laravel 5.2, and pass to my controller method the $request:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Input, Session, Exception, Request;

class WebController extends Controller {

   public function myfunction(Request $request) {
      $request->fullUrl(); 
   }

}
```

But Laravel return me this error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::fullUrl()
```

In the docs for the 5.2 version all is right:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests

This method fullUrl exits in the Request.php file ...

What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are importing the `Request` *Facade*, which is resolving to a `Request` facade instance when you type hint in your controller's method.

Instead, import the actual `Request` object:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

If you must use the facade as well, you can do something like:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Request as RequestFacade;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `Request` from `use Input, Session, Exception, Request;` 
and add new line:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

So final code look like:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Input, Session, Exception;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class WebController extends Controller {

   public function myfunction(Request $request) {
      $request->fullUrl(); 
   }

}
```

Hope this help you well!